# Find out If a list of (x,y) coordinates span a row or column in a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

So, I have a list of x,y coordiates. I want to find out whether that list of coordinates span all rows of a matrix of values and same for columns.

i.e.

```
T F F F

T T F F

F T F F

F T T F
```

Here the group of T's are provided as coordinates so it would be something like `[(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)]`. How can i find out using these coordinates that the set they describe spans all rows of the matrix? This also applies to columns, as well as both ( so, whether the set spans both rows and columns ).

The values are currently stored as `vector<vector<coord>>` where coord is a struct like :

```
struct coord {
    int x, int y;
}
```

Comment: Is your example "spans rows but not columns" "spans columns but not rows", "spans neither rows nor columns" or "spans both rows and columns"?

Comment: @Caleth - The example is "spans rows but not columns", the T is located in each row but not in each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all you have is the size of the matrix `(m x n = row x column`) and the position of `T`'s in term of coordinates (`std::vector<std::vector<coord>>`), you can do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<coord>> Ts_pos;
std::set<int> rows;
std::set<int> cols;

bool spansRow = false;
bool spansCol = false;

for (int i = 0; i < Ts_pos.size(); i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < Ts_pos[i].size(); j++)
   {
      item = Ts_pos[i][j];

      cols.insert(item.x);
      rows.insert(item.y);
   }
}

if (rows.size() == numRows) spansRow = true;
if (cols.size() == numCols) spansCol = true;
```

After executing the loop, the two `set` will contain the index number of the rows and of the columns touched by the T's, i.e: consider, in you exemple, the first T. It has coordinates (0,0) so it touches the column with index 0 and the row with the index 0, so you insert 0 in the row set and 0 in the col set. Then, you consider the second T in your list and so on.

Outside the loop, you can discover if all rows have been touched simply querying for the size of the row set. If it is equal to the number of rows of the matrix, then, all the rows have been touched and the set of T's spans the matrix by row, at least.
The same you do for the column set.

Then you can `std::cout` what you want according to the value of `spansRow` and `spansCol`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to de-duplicate the `x`s and the `y`s, and compare them to the required indexes. E.g.

```
std::set<int> required = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // values that must be present

bool spans_direction(const std::vector<coord> & coords, std::function<int(coord)> projection)
{
  std::set<int> projected;   
  std::transform(coords.begin(), coords.end(), std::inserter(projected, projected.end()), projection);
  return projected == required;
}

bool spans_cols(const std::vector<coord> & coords)
{
  return spans_direction(coords, [](coord c) { return c.x; });
}

bool spans_rows(const std::vector<coord> & coords)
{
  return spans_direction(coords, [](coord c) { return c.y; });
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I am a little too new to C++. Could you please explain the algorithm you are going for? I don't really know all the library functions and I will be trying to decode all of this but a quick explaination of what's happening would be helpful.

Are you basically seperating all the x values and then adding them to a set so they are non-duplicated and then just comparing with required?

Comment: Yes, the x values for cols and the y values for rows

Answer (score 0):

We can store all the x-coordinates and all the y-coordinates in separate vectors, sort these vectors and check if values from **0-n** are present in each vector (where n is the no. of rows for x-vector and no. of columns for y-vector).

Missing values, values ranging to less than **n**, values starting from greater than 0, etc will provide us with the answer whether the set spans both rows and columns.